# Difference between the different measurement metric

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, f1score, score

Can someone explain what each of these mean? both in simple terms and in terms of TP, TN, FP, FN?

Also are there any other common metrics that I am missing?

1. F-measure or F-score
2. Recall
3. Precision
4. Accuracy

Comment: Fyi there's a good explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is the first link which appear on Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you are creating a model to predict whether a person has a disease or not.

**True Positives (TP)**: Model predicts yes (they have the disease), and they do have the disease.

**True Negatives (TN)**: Model predicts no, and they don't have the disease.

**False Positives (FP)**: Model predicts yes, but they don't actually have the disease. (Also known as a "Type I error.")

**False Negatives (FN)**: Model predicts no, but they actually do have the disease. (Also known as a "Type II error.")

If you look at confusion metric below
[image]

```
Accuracy: Overall, how often is the classifier correct?
(TP+TN)/total = (100+50)/165 = 0.91

True Positive Rate: When it's actually yes, how often does it predict yes?
TP/actual yes = 100/105 = 0.95
also known as "Sensitivity" or "Recall"

Precision: Model predicts yes, how often is it correct?
TP/predicted yes = 100/110 = 0.91

F1 Score = 2 * (Precision * Recall)/ Precision + Recall
         =  2 * .91 * .95 / (0.91+.95)
```

Other terms which people usually use are :

1. AUC - Area Under Curve
2. Cohen's Kappa